# back-end checkboxes not displaying after switch to Shoreditch

Tags: css, shoreditch

After switching to the shoreditch theme, the checkboxes on our back-end site are not displaying appropriately in all situations.

When listing Contacts from a search, the checkboxes that should be in the left column only show up if you click in that column within a few seconds after the page loads. If you wait a bit, they do not show up at all.

When merging contacts, the checkboxes to select what data to merge do not show up at all.

I haven't exhaustively looked at every instance, but Checkboxes display appropriately when listing a Contribution search.

I can replicate this behavior on both Chrome and Safari. CSS shows the following in /media/civicrm/custom_ext/org.civicrm.shoreditch-master/css/custom-civicrm.css?r=65LNz:

```
.crm-container input[type=checkbox], .crm-container input[type=radio] {
    display: none;}
```

This css file is so large that I'm cautious about just unsetting the display property, not knowing exactly what cascade that might cause. Anyone have a clue about this?

Further, as part of the extension, I assume any edits to this file will be overwritten on the next update.

Is there a location where I can set up my own custom css file for Civi (other than my global CSS.) while still using the Shoreditch theme? (We've been using a custom civi css file up to now, but that's not an option with Shoreditch.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've discovered that the Shoreditch README states that "At the moment the theme is being developed to work only in Drupal." The CiviCRM extension page for Shoreditch, however, states, "CMS Compatibility: 
CMS Independent (CiviCRM-native)". Shoreditch, however, is still required for Mosaico, which **does** work correctly with Joomla.

So, apparently, my expectations that Shoreditch will work correctly as the Civi theme with my Joomla installation are incorrect, and I'll move back to my custom css.

It would be helpful if the extension page would clarify what Shoreditch is expected to do and not do for non-drupal users.